# Interpreting sys.dm_os_sys_memory

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I'm trying to figure out a way(using only TSQL) to determine if and how much the PAGEFILE is used (I will capitalize this term if I refer to the windows page file from now on - like pagefileusage% counter).

My first thought is using sys.dm_os_sys_memory. I am a little bit confused here.
The description of the **total_page_file_kb** is that this is a commit limit, so basically, it's the size of the physical memory (RAM) + size of the PAGEFILE.  So far it is ok.
But what exactly is the **available_page_file_kb**?
Is it referring to the commit limit or to the PAGEFILE?
I tried to use these calculations:

Assuming that **available_page_file_kb** referring to the commit limit:

PAGEFILE usage% = (**available_page_file_kb**-**available_physical_memory_kb**) / (**total_page_file_kb**-**total_physical_memory_kb**)

Assuming that **available_page_file_kb** is referring to the PAGEFILE

PAGEFILE usage% = (**available_page_file_kb**) / (**total_page_file_kb**-**total_physical_memory_kb**)

Unfortunately none of these calculations show me the right results.
I keep checking the pagefileusage% counter on some of my test servers, and sometimes the first formula is wrong by only 1-3% and the second one by 15-25% or vice versa, the second one by 1-3% and the first one by 15-25%,

What did I miss here? Is it impossible to determine (or even just get a close estimate) the pagefileusage% with sys.dm_os_sys_memory dmv?

Comment: Maybe this article helps on clarifying the counter itself? Are you using the right definition? http://blogs.technet.com/b/perfguru/archive/2008/01/08/explanation-of-pagefile-usage-as-reported-in-the-task-manager.aspx

Comment: You said *Assuming that available_page_file_kb referring to the commit limit* and you also said 8Assuming that available_page_file_kb is referring to the PAGEFILE* what are you actually trying to find out. Do you want to find out SQL Server memory paged or Windows memory paged ?

Comment: @Shanky: paging file % usage performance counter is an essential counter for servers which hosts SQL Server services. The smaller this number the better for SQL Server. But this counter is OS related so it cannot be selected via sys.dm_os_performance_counters. I would like to find a way to get this counter's value (or close estimate) from inside SQL Server using TSQL.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running into this due to rounding?  How many decimal points are being used?

Comment: @stacylaray: I think it is not rounding issue. The formula divides two positive integer. Rounding could cause only +/- 1 deflection top.

Comment: It would help a lot if you added some **actual numbers from your server** and **what you expect**, to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you need to take into account the **System Cache** and **Kernel Memory** pages?

It would help a lot if you added some *actual numbers from your server* and *what you expect*, to your question.

For example, here is my test server's memory state:

[image: memory stats for a test server]

The code is:

```
SELECT 'Page File' AS MemoryType
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * total_page_file_kb / 1024) AS Total_MB
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * available_page_file_kb / 1024) AS Free_MB
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1),
        100.0 * available_page_file_kb / total_page_file_kb)) + '%' AS Free
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Physical (RAM)'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * total_physical_memory_kb / 1024)
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * available_physical_memory_kb / 1024)
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1),
        100.0 * available_physical_memory_kb / total_physical_memory_kb)) + '%'
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Non-Physical'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),
         1.0 * (total_page_file_kb - total_physical_memory_kb) / 1024)
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),
         1.0 * (available_page_file_kb - available_physical_memory_kb) / 1024)
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 1),
       100.0 * (available_page_file_kb - available_physical_memory_kb)
             / (total_page_file_kb - total_physical_memory_kb))) + '%'
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'System Cache',CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * system_cache_kb / 1024),NULL,NULL
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kernel: Paged'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * kernel_paged_pool_kb / 1024),NULL,NULL
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kernel: Non-Paged'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 1.0 * kernel_nonpaged_pool_kb / 1024),NULL,NULL
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory
ORDER BY Total_MB DESC
```